# Android Volley: How to parseNetworkResponse large response in small batches?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parsing, android-volley

I am using Volley for making network requests and parsing them to show data in my android app.

Currently, I am using `Volley's` functions:

`override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse?): Response<Any> {....return Response.success(sectionData, null)}`

and

`override fun deliverResponse(response: Any?) {....}`

to achieve this.

Unfortunately the parsing I am doing in `parseNetworkResponse` takes a few second to finish. The data I am parsing contains of hundreds of rows and I don't have control over the server. Ideally I would like to be able to parse lets say 50 rows and show it in my recyclerview so the user had something to look at while I parse the rest of the data and add it to the recycler view adapter.

Is there a way to achieve this sort of small batches parsing?

**EDIT:** I have figured out a workaround solution which works for me. I placed the following in the `parseNetworkResponse` right after I add each parsed row:

```
if (sectionData.size >= 50) {
    val toSend = SectionData(sectionHeaderTitle,ArrayList())
    toSend.data.addAll(sectionData)
    sectionData.clear()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        deliverResponse(toSend)
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way or not but it works fine for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a workaround solution which works for me. I placed the following in the `parseNetworkResponse` right after I add each parsed row:

```
if (sectionData.size >= 50) {
    val toSend = SectionData(sectionHeaderTitle,ArrayList())
    toSend.data.addAll(sectionData)
    sectionData.clear()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        deliverResponse(toSend)
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way or not but it works fine for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no. `Volley` is only responsible for handover the data you requested from the server. Parsing is done in several ways, mostly using the `GSON` library. If you want, you can use `worker` to parse data in the background and store it in `DataStore` as a small portion, and then access the data.

It actually depends on what you actually want. If you want to avoid storing lots of data in memory during runtime, you might consider a one-time parse then break it into small pieces of your preferred size, and store it in `DataStore` as JsonString or in the database like `Room`, then access it from there. If your system has a large chunk of data, you may consider using a local database for this purpose. As the parser doesn't know about the data structure generally, it's not possible to know the count of rows before parsing the data.